# Helm chart is fetchable but not searchable

Tags: helm-tls

I have helm charts for a project `my-project` uploaded to a repo `myrepo`. Using `helm` v3.5.3, if I run

```sh
helm repo update
helm fetch myrepo/my-project --version 0.0.1
```

It downloads the `my-project-0.0.1.tgz` file I had pushed to `myrepo`. But when I run

```sh
helm repo update
helm search repo myrepo/my-project
```

I get no results.

Why is this?